# What does "bad someone for doing" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [The Markenmore Mystery](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59818/59818-h/59818-h.htm#toc1) (1922) by J. S. Fletcher, a detective was talking to a sexton about a murdered man:

> “I suppose Mr. Guy Markenmore was pretty mad about her at that time, eh?” suggested Blick.
>
> “Umph!” said Cripps. “Runned after her a deal, he did, to be sure. But he was a **powerful bad ’un for** running after women-folk of all sorts, high and low—turned the heads of half the lasses in this village, he did! Lord bless ’ee, he was always a-making love, **all round**—couldn’t help it, seemed so. Left some aching hearts behind him, did Master Guy when he went away to London town.”

1- What does "bad someone for doing" mean?
2- What could be the suitable meaning of "all round" in this context?

Comment: "all round" could mean he was dating (a)round - he was going out on dates with (a lot of) different girls. "bad" could mean he was unsuccessful in doing so (1) or people perceived his lifestyle as immoral (2), or he was notoriously known for this behaviour (3)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It's (2) and/or (3). "He was a bad 'un" (one) is an implied criticism. Another traditional expression for a woman's unwise choice of husband or lover is "a wrong 'un".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat dated regional dialect, so you should not expect a straightforward description in modern English.

He was a constant/regular/frequent flirt/skirt chaser/womanizer. That's the "powerful" and "running after women-folk". I think "bad un(one)" adds to the power as well as suggesting that the behavior is antisocial. He was in fact very good at it, not bad, since he "turned the heads of half the lasses".

"All round" is essentially all over the neighborhood, non stop. any time of day ...